# Python: Converting from a list to a string

Tags: python, string, list

I'm having problems with a homework question.

> "Write a function, to_str(a), that takes an array, a, converts each of
>   its elements to a string (using str(a[i])) and appends all these
>   strings together."

This is what I have

```
def to_str(a):
    for i in a: a.append([i])
    return str(a[i])
```

I have no idea how to use str(a[i]), I was wondering if someone can point me to the right direction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs:

> str(object) -> string
>
> Return a nice string representation of the object. If the argument is
>   a string, the return value is the same object.

So `str(a[i])` will return a string representation of `a[i]`, i.e. convert `a[i]` to a string.
You will then need to concatenates the strings for all values of `i`.

As for your code, I have the following comments:

- `i` is an element of `a`, not an index, as you might be thinking;
- you are appending elements of `a` to `a` (endlessly, I'm afraid);
- `a[i]` can cause an exception, because, like I said, `i` is an element, not an index;
- you need to return a concatenation of strings, not a string from one element.

Also, if using `str(a[i])` is not strictly mandatory, I'd suggest to skip it as unpythonic. You don't need indexes at all for this. Examples:

```
''.join(str(element) for element in a)
```

or

```
''.join(map(str, a))
```

will return what you need. In both cases `str` is applied to all elements of `a`.

The simplest-to-understand ("beginner") way without using indexes will be

```
s = ''
for element in a:
    s += str(element)
return s
```

It's a bit less efficient, though it does effectively the same thing.

Comment: I think it's cleaner to loop over the elements of `a` itself rather than looping over the indices.

Comment: @DSM Me too, too bad it's a part of the assignment. I've added that to my answer, too.

Comment: @Tadeck I already took back my downvote; this doesn't change the fact that your answer contained incorrect code for quite a bit of the time when this question received most of the attention. As for `reduce`, I have nothing against it, but I wouldn't advice it to a newcomer without a verbose enough explanation. This question is, in old terms, a `[homework]` question, so the answer quality depends a lot on the verbosity, not elegance. Anyway, the right thing to use here is `str.join`, not `reduce`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Converting each element into a string is easiest to use list comprehension:

```
[ str(i) for i in a ]
# equivalent to
[ str(a[i]) for i in range(len(a)) ]
# equivalent to
map(str, a) # most concise, use if you want to feel incredibly clever...
```

So you can write the function:

```
def to_str2(a):
    ''.join([str(i) for i in a]) # concatenates the list as a list of strings
```

.

Your code *nearly* does this:

```
def to_str(a):
    new_a = [] # rather than use the same a!
    for i in a:
        new_a.append(str(i)) #convert i to string before appending
    return new_a
```

Answer (score 0):

The code meeting all the task criteria is rather something like:

```
def to_str(a):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + str(y), a, '')
```

Which does things exactly in the mentioned way: first converts them to strings, then adds to the string made from already processed elements (which at the beginning is just emty string).

**EDIT**: The clearer (and supported by Python 3) way is to use explicit looping through elements. It does exactly the same, clarifying at the same time how reduce() works:

```
def to_str(a):
    result = ''  # third argument of reduce()
    for item in a:
        result += str(item)  # does what reduce() lambda argument was doing
    return result
```

Comment: +1 (not sure why down voted, but perhaps `reduce` is confusing without explanation?) I however, like map/reduce solutions :)

Comment: Wasn't me -- I comment instead of downvoting -- but the (just-deleted) first one didn't work, and the second one (by comparison with something like `''.join(str(elem) for elem in a)` uses the out-of-favour reduce, introduces a lambda function and two non-obviously-named variables, and shows quadratic behaviour.  [Or maybe the downvoter was being really literal about using `a[i]` and looping over the indices, who knows?]

Comment: My downvote was due to the incorrect first snippet; undownvoted.

Comment: @hayden: I have added alternate solution doing the same as reduce(). Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score -1):

the simplest way is:

```
[str(i) for i in a]
```

if you want a function:

```
def to_str(a):
    return [str(i) for i in a]
```

Comment: That solves the first part of the problem, not the "appends all these strings together" part.